# Cross-platform AES LightWeight Encryption Library

Tags: library, cross-platform, encryption

I’m working on a small project and trying to find the best-suited encryption library for my purposes. Searching blindly yields too many results for me. Here’s what I’m looking for:

- Cross-platform. WIN/OSX/Android/iOS
- Straightforward AES encryption. I’m not looking for a myriad of encryption standards
- Able to encrypt files and decrypt to memory without using temporary files
- Small, easy to work with and understand
- The language does not matter as long as the library achieves cross-compatibility.

To provide context, my project is a simple exercise in cross-platform development.

- Create and store encrypted text files through a program using the library
- Access said text files on a different platform using another program
- The two programs will be native applications, but share the encryption library to simplify compatibility